# Comment on an update in linkedin from android application

Tags: android, comments, linkedin-api

Can anyone help me to send a comment/reply on a particular post in linkedin?

I am able to send direct message to linked in via my android application using following code using person id.

```
id = update.getUpdateContent().getPerson().getId()
```

.....

```
LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = new LinkedInAccessToken(
            linkedInTokens[0], linkedInTokens[1]);
    LinkedInApiClientFactory clientFactory = LinkedInApiClientFactory
            .newInstance(LinkedInConstants.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY,
                    LinkedInConstants.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    LinkedInApiClient client = clientFactory
            .createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
    client.sendMessage(Arrays.asList(id), "subjectText",
                    "postingText");
```

can anyone help me to reply a post?

Thank you

Comment: Please anyone help me on this..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the network update key of the update you'd like to comment on, the API call to do this would be:

POST http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates/key={NETWORK UPDATE KEY}/update-comments

An example of the XML body of the comment:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<update-comment>
  <comment>Really great article!</comment>
</update-comment>
```